# Why hadoop yarn mapreduce stuck or hanging on running job state?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, jobs, freeze, hadoop-yarn

I have a wordcount sample mapreduce job and I ran it with YARN mode. But why my mapreduce job stop and not continue while running job step? It's like this :

```
15/04/04 17:18:21 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1428142358448_0002
15/04/04 17:18:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1428142358448_0002/
15/04/04 17:18:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1428142358448_0002
```

I've try to tweak in yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml and nothing happend. That's still hang on that's state. It's about memory or about my wrong configuration.

I need your suggest all...Thanks

Comment: What kind of services are running on the nodes? For me the JobHistory was missing on the master

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same situation. My wordcount program got stuck at Running Job: job_xxxxxxxxxx.
What I did was I rebooted the system and gave it a try again and it worked. I was using ubuntu on oracle virtual box. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Check the status of the job in your resource manager port. By default, 8088 is the port number where resource manager will be available. You should be able to see the status of the job and job history and etc.

Comment: Thanks before ...in the web page : 8088, it says that state=accepted, finalstatus=undefined and tracking url=undefined. But it's still stuck and not continue. Has it because of memory? Thanks a lot...

Comment: There must be something wrong, I'm not sure about undefined status, can you restart all your daemons and run the job again?

Comment: I've done that many times, but the result still same hahahah. It's very weird, cause on the past I could do that, and no hang at all. I'm sure that my configuration is not wrong, do you think this cause my computer?

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

You should check the content of yarn-site.xml
In the file, if the value of yarn.node.manager.aux-service contains invalid characters such as '.' the job don't work.

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce.shuffle</value>
</property>
```

If the value contains such a character, you should replace the character '_',then the stacking job are working.